# Launching R gui from the command line and setting the working directory to the current folder

Tags: r

On a Mac, is there a way to launch the default R gui from the command line, with the working directory set to the current folder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

assuming R.app is in your Applications folder:

```
open -a /Applications/R.app .
```